# How to get IE10 back in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

Somehow I uninstalled IE10 in Windows 8 Pro. Is there a way to repair/reinstall IE10 in Windows 8?

When I go to the IE10 download site my options are

1. download 32- or 64-bit IE10 beta for Windows 7 (not me)
2. buy Windows 8 (I already did)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably disabled it. Open the Control Panel and go to Programs and Features. On the right, click "Turn Windows features on or off". A list box will pop up, check the box for "Internet Explorer 10". Hit OK and when done, you should have IE back.

Comment: Thanks! This does it! Sorry for the delay; the re-install required a restart and I forgot about my question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have the desktop Internet Explorer? Did the IE10 tile change to the desktop IE tile? If you set another browser as the default browser, then Windows 8 always starts desktop IE. If you change your default browser back to IE, the Windows Store version will show back up on the Windows 8 start screen.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff, but this wasn't about default app. Somehow I had disabled IE10, but K.A.'s solution worked.